# Noise everywhere on solderless breadboard, could the DC-DC converter be the source?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, breadboard

I am using a solderless bread to prototype an analog sense -> 8 bit digital circuit.

- It's messy
- Has Hi gain sensing opamps
- sensitive POTS

I have 20mV of noise everywhere, even when I am connecting GND to GND at a different locations... All of my ICs have decoupling caps. Putting more caps on the rails has no noticeable effect.

I assumed this is just from breadboards being terrible.

**My question is could the DC-DC converter be the source of this noise?**  If so I need to have a linear regulator power the analog electronics.

Comment: Yes but you need to search for my answers with better probing techniques, low ESR caps, and twisted pair q&a’s

Comment: I'd suggest putting up a circuit diagram,along with a part number and link to the datasheet for the DC to DC converter. I also suggest carefully reading that data sheet, and looking for traps -- for example, some DCDC converters have a minimum  load, and/or specific instructions for an output tank cap.

Comment: If you have 20mV noise everywhere, I'd suggest testing the osciloscope, if it works properly

Comment: A picture of your breadboard would also be useful

Comment: Have you looked at the specs for your DC-DC converter?  20mV ripple may be normal.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys, it was the scope...

It wasn't obvious because when I directly connected the 2 probe ends I got a clean 0v DC... However, adding jumper wire created the noise.